# Ternary Operator in Xaml in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin form apps. I wanted to to set Grdiview backgroud color based on condition of properties.

I know I can create a new property in class file and then bind to xaml but is there way to use ternary condition in Xaml itself.

my code is

```
<Grid Margin="5,0,5,5" Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="White">
```

This Grid being bind to model , which is having property IsRead ( null-able Boolean). Now I want to put condition that when IsRead is true then set Background color to Grey, otherwise White.

How can I do that within xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard about such a thing, but you can use a converter instead. It's your best choice. It's clean, reusable and easy programmable.

Here is a well elaborated solution to this kind of need (surely you can do it in lots of ways, this one is just one).

**Create a struct to make the solution completely reusable:**

```
public struct NullableBoolColorScheme
{
    public Color TrueColor { get; set; }
    public Color FalseColor { get; set; }
    public Color NullColor { get; set; }

    public NullableBoolColorScheme(Color trueColor, Color falseColor, Color nullColor)
    {
        TrueColor = trueColor;
        FalseColor = falseColor;
        NullColor = nullColor;
    }

    public Color GetColor(bool? value)
    {
        if (!value.HasValue)
            return NullColor;
        else
            return value.Value ? TrueColor : FalseColor;
    }
}
```

**Create your converter:**

```
public class NullableBoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool?)) return null;

        Color returningColor = Color.Default;

        if (parameter != null && parameter is NullableBoolColorScheme)
            returningColor = ((NullableBoolColorScheme)parameter).GetColor((value as bool?));

        return returningColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("Conversion not allowed");
    }
}
```

**Handle it in your ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel // Remember to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise property changes
{
    public bool? MyNullableBoolProperty
    {
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public NullableBoolColorScheme AppColorScheme { get; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AppColorScheme = new NullableBoolColorScheme(Color.Gray, Color.White, Color.Transparent /* Some possibilities are open here =) */);
    }
}
```

**Use it in XAML:**

```
<!-- Declare your namespace -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Namespace.Converters"
         ...
         >
<!-- Create your resources dictionary and add a converter instance -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:NullableBoolToColorConverter x:Key="NullableBoolToColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <!-- Have fun -->
    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,5" 
          Padding="10"  
          BackgroundColor="{Binding MyNullableBoolProperty, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NullableBoolToColorConverter}, ConverteParameter={Binding AppColorScheme}}">
        ...
    </Grid>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Binding on ConverterParameter not works. But to do it i've declared a ressource :
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="ColorsBorderValues" Type="{x:Type Color}">
            <Color>Black</Color>
            <Color>#bfbfbf</Color>
            <Color>Transparent</Color>
        </x:Array>
</ContentPage.Resources>

And linked it into ConverterParameter :
{Binding myProperty, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NullableBoolToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ColorsBorderValues}}

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Ternary in XAML.

**Solution 1 (Using Converter):**

You can probably go with using `ValueConverter`. Create a Converter which implements `IValueConverter`.

```
public class ReadUnReadToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            bool? isRead = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            if(isRead.HasValue && isRead.Value == true)
            {
                return Color.Grey;                    
            }    
            return Color.White;
    }

    //You may not need the Convert Back method. This will need to convert Color back to Boolean
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML Resource, add this class as a static resource, then you can use this converter to bind value and convert based on this.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>      
   <local:ReadUnReadToColorConverter x:Key="ReadUnReadToColorConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Now, Bind this Converter to your Grid as follows:

```
<Grid Margin="5,0,5,5" Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="{Binding IsRead, Converter={StaticResource ReadUnReadToColorConverter}}">
```

**Solution 2 (Using Property Binding (OneWay solution only)):**

You can simply have a `Color` Property in your `ViewModel` and return value in the `get` method of the property based on the condition as follows:

```
public Color ReadUnReadBackgroundColor
{
    get
    {
        if(IsRead.HasValue && IsRead.Value == true)
        {
            return Color.Grey;                    
        }    
        return Color.White;            
    }
}
```

Now Bind this with Grid's `BackgroundColor` Property:

```
<Grid Margin="5,0,5,5" Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="{Binding ReadUnReadBackgroundColor}">
```